# 'Absolute path' error with SQLiteConnection.CreateFile

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Plugins\\Data.sqlite");
```

When run, this give me this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Absolute path information is required

How can I fix this?

Comment: So what does `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` return?

Comment: C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Coding\minet-server

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(
    Path.Combine(
        Application.ExecutablePath,
        "Plugins",
        "Data.sqlite"
    )
);
```

Comment: I can't use Application.ExecutablePath for some reason

Comment: I'm using a .dll not an .exe